# How to use the bearer code in Twitter API requests?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, twitter

I can not retrieve data from twitter even after generating a Bearer code. An example of a request is:

```
    var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=1125750390664892417";
    var bearer = 'Bearer '+ 'myBearer code';
    fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then((anyResponse) => {
        console.log(anyResponse);
    }) .catch(error => console.log('Something bad happened ' + error.message)
    );
```

I do not understand what could be possibly wrong, but It always fails. I have obtained the bearer code following this page (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/bearer-tokens). But I did not encode any of my keys (as I have read here it was necessary, but the twitter page doesnt say so). Does somebody have an idea what could possibly go wrong with my request ???

Thanks!

Comment: Here is some code that may or may not help you answer your own question https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/TwitterAPI/BearerAuth.py

Comment: Seems cool! Thanks. I will scrape through.

Comment: Everything must be encoded. I got confused by the page I have posted, but here there is a step by step which seems more helpful and in accordance with other posts in StackOverflow: 

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only

Answer (score 0):

For me, it finally worked in Postman when I used the bearer code without the base64 encryption. However, It goes against the docu and the nice python coded commented by a user above.

I still did not implement in my JS code, but since it is working is Postman, I can imagine that any XHR request with the same credentials should also work. Thanks for the help!